# Rails: turbolinks:load event is fired before body content changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm building a code blog on a rails 5.1.6 app that uses turbolinks 5.2.0.

I want to do a really simple thing, which is highlight the code (using a js plugin) after the content is loaded, so I added this to the page:

```
coffee:
  $(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
    Highlighter.init()
```

That works well on a fresh load. However, when you're in another page and you click a link to go there, the `turbolinks:load` **event is fired before the content is updated**, so the highlight doesn't work.

Do you know what's happening or how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
I know `turbolinks:load` is fired before the content changes because I tried adding a `debugger`:

```
coffee:
  $(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
    debugger # => This is called before new content is rendered
    Highlighter.init()
```

**EDIT 2:**
This is the simple `Highlighter.init()`:

```
class Highlighter
  @init: ->
    console.log "Trying to highlight"
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem to call Highlighter.init() multiple times. How do you know that "turbolinks:load" is fired before content is updated?

Comment: @WizardofOgz Because I added a debugger and it was called before it changes (see my edit)

Comment: The DOM can be updated before you actually see it rendered. It is good that the turbolinks:load event is fired at that point because you can make changes without triggering a repaint. Inspect the DOM at your debugger breakpoint to see if the expected changes are there but not yet rendered.

Comment: @WizardofOgz Ok, thanks for explaining that. But how do I do to execute a piece of code after the content is rendered? It's not an uncommon use case. I've checked and changes are not in the DOM.

Comment: What highlighter plugin are you using? Is it open source, and if so, would it be possible to link to it?

Comment: @DomChristie Yes, it's open source (https://highlightjs.org/). However, there is no problem with the plugin. It actually highlights rendered content, and it works fine when loading the fresh page, it just won't work when clicking a link that gets you to  that page (so when turbolinks visits the page) because at the point the `turbolinks:load` is triggered, the content is not there to highlight yet.

Comment: Thanks. One final question: can you paste the content of Highlight.init()? It looks like that’s wrapping the highlightjs API, and it’s important to know how it’s being initialised. I have tested Turbolinks v5.2 and have access to the new document body on turbolinks:load, so I’m thinking the issue is to do with initialisation

Comment: @DomChristie See my last edit. I've tried this in quite a lot of ways anyway. But every way ends up in the same result: debugger being called before page content changes. And again, take into account it works fine when you refresh the page.

Comment: @ArielScherman and if you like my answer, please upvote it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()` sets up the plugin to work on *only* `DOMContentLoaded` or `load`](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/cf4b46e5b7acfe2626a07914e1d0d4ef269aed4a/src/highlight.js#L676-L679). These events are only called on the initial page load, so after that, they are never called again.

Here's the order of relevant events:

1. `DOMContentLoaded`
2. `turbolinks:load` (your code sets up highlighter to be called on `load`)
3. `load` (which initialises highlighting)
4. Navigate to another page
5. `turbolinks:load` (your code sets up highlighter to be called on `load`)
6. That's it! `load` is not triggered again until a full page load

To fix this you'll need to follow the [Custom Initialization](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js#custom-initialization) instructions and adapt them for Turbolinks:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

I'd recommend that this is included in your main application JavaScript file. Adding event handlers in inline script tags in the `<body>` can often cause problems unless they are properly removed.